# Understanding Magento Registry

Tags: session, registry, singleton

I have been wondering always, where is all the registry data stored in Magento ?

I know that even **singleton** objects are stored in the registry. And registry is just a static array variable of the **Mage** class.

I have a couple of questions here to clear my confusion:

1. Is registry different for different users ? I mean is it created on
       a per-user (per **HTTP** request) basis?

For example,

> ```
> Mage::register('foo', 'Hello World'); //set a value for foo
> Mage::registry('foo'); //will this return hello world for all HTTP users ?
> ```

2. Is registry data stored in
           sessions ? If not how will Magento identify which user invoked the
           registry data ?

I have read Alan Storm's [blog article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial) as well as his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049575/magento-getsingleton-confusion/8051538#8051538) on StackOverFlow regarding this. But I couldn't kill the confusion. Please correct me If I you think my basics are messed up. Thanks

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049575/magento-getsingleton-confusion/8051538#8051538

Comment: thanks Amit Bera, I was reading that article and SOF answer by Alan before posting this question. I couldn't quite get my answers from there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The registry stores data to memory which is specific to that *request* (rather than user or anything else), and persists for the duration of that request only.  The principle is very simple really, the `Mage` class is instantiated as a singleton object for every request and the instantiated Mage object remains in memory, and is accessible in all classes (and templates) until the request completes and the response is sent.

As the object is a singleton, whenever you access it you get the same object.  All that is happening is that you are storing values to this object, so when one class stores a value, and another accesses it they are both working on the same object and the second class is able to retrieve the value the first class set.

Comment: So its alive only for ONE request ? Meaning if I load a page in Magento, one request is DONE and registry data is flushed ?

Comment: Yes values you set with `Mage::register()` persist for that request only.  If you want to store user specific data you should use the session, the registry is really just designed to make data portable between classes.

Comment: that makes sense! Same applies to singleton instance as well ?

Comment: Yes exactly the same - if you look at the `getSingleton()` method of the `Mage` class it actually stores the data to the registry.

Answer (score 3):

The registry is stored in memory and is per HTTP request, so you are not able to share data between different requests or users.

Comment: But how will Magento map the HTTP Request and registry ?

Answer (score 2):

Magento Registry stored in the **application’s memory**.

when ever your script is done running, whatever you had stored in the registry is gone, so there is no need to worry about clearing it out (unless the script you are running is storing large objects in the registry and is looping through a lot of data).

In such case, you have  to unregister your entries when you are done with them.

the Registry is just a static property of the Mage class.
see for [details](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/Mage.php#L63-L68)

but still I couldn’t really find out a good explanation

2) for each users there will be separate registry per request on server.

hope this will make little clear in your mind

Comment: thanks liyakat. I read http://prattski.com/2014/09/23/using-the-magento-registry-mageregister/ before posting :P But how will Magento map the variable and user ?

Comment: @Hashid, you can get more idea with Alan's blog as well. how registry is working with each request in code follow. http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial

Comment: read that as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you can implement registry. I have given live example in my tutorial video you can see.

https://youtu.be/PWeDOGQbOfo

If you have any confusion regarding registry pattern you can reply me. I assure you i will solve your confusion.