# Magento 2 : How to get current product programmatically in a helper?

Tags: magento2, product, url, helper, registry

Could someone advise what's the best way to get the current product in a custom helper? Basically if I am a product page I need to get it's sku

Comment: Helpers are usually used as elements/methods that are global and always available. Helpers can be called anywhere and you only need to inject them in the class. I think you should create a block class which should have the code as per shared in answer below. That shall solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context        
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
)
{        
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{        
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}
```

Comment: I always get the response of null when I call this. Could you advise anymore?

Comment: @Goose84 i am not sure about it but please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44299/understanding-magento-registry/44306#44306
it may help you thanks

Answer (score 0):

**To get the current product:**

**use block class**: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View

**Get product using**: $block->getProduct() in your phtml or use the class and get in the block file.

Hope it Helps.Happy coding!!